# Can't get a view to change it's size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UIImageView` inside a `ForecastCell Class` (for a `UICollectionView`), anyhow, I can't get the `UIImageView` inside the cell to change it's size. This is what I tried:

```
private func setupWeatherIcon(){
    self.addSubview(mWeatherIcon)

   //mWeatherIcon.frame.size.width = CGFloat(self.frame.width) / 2
   //mWeatherIcon.frame.size.height = CGFloat(self.frame.height) / 2
   mWeatherIcon.frame.size.width = 20
   mWeatherIcon.frame.size.height = 20

   mWeatherIcon.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
   mWeatherIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

This is mWeatherIcon:

```
var mWeatherIcon: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "partly-cloudy"))

    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()
```

No matter what width and height I set, It always stays the same width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need width and height constraints

```
self.contentView.addSubview(mWeatherIcon)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   mWeatherIcon.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:contentView.centerXAnchor),
   mWeatherIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:contentView.centerYAnchor),
   mWeatherIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:contentView.widthAnchor,multiplier:0.5),
   mWeatherIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:contentView.heightAnchor,multiplier:0.5)
])
```

Don't forget to implement this method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Comment: I don't want it to be really 20 20, just an example. I tried giving it self.widthanchor and divide it by 2 but it didn't even build, I tried casting but still nothing. How can I get the self.widthanchor to be the width of the image?